# Port knocking and RSA encryption

Tags: python, rsa, public-key

I am doing on my project and there is about port knocking. I have 3 files that separated in server side and client.
In the server contains : portknocking server as a daemon and configuration file [contains sequence of port that must be satisfied and many other configuration detail]
In the client contains : portknocking client.

Is there possible to encrypt sequence port number in file configuration using RSA..If so,, how to do that??

thank you

PS: I am running daemon at server[it reads file configuration] and then I run program on client and specify sequence port number [if port number sequence is same with configuration file then it is connected]..

Comment: are you suggesting encrypting port number, but then runnihng unencrypted data over the port?

Comment: why bother encrypting the configuration file? It is present only on your server.

Comment: @GregS : presumably for client config...

Comment: @mitch Wheat : Yes. I sent SYN packet on the ports..and I want encrypt sequence of port so that an attacker can not know exactly the right combination of sequence port that used for sending SYN packet.
@GregS : I am not encrypting the config file, I am just encrypting port sequence that prespecified on config file. Yes, it is only on my server. I do this due to administrator can change the sequence port and other configuration easily

Answer (score 1):

> Is there possible to encrypt sequence port number in file configuration using RSA.

Yes.

> how to do that??

You might try a bit of searching for a [python rsa library](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+rsa+library).

However, if you're planning on doing this on the client side, then realize in order for the client program to decrypt the data, it will have to have a decryption key. If the client program has the decryption key, then anyone with a text editor also has the decryption key (and the code to decrypt it).

If you *really* meant [RSA](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/apidoc/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html) encryption, take a look at [PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/).